# Why isupper() function doesnt work in if condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase, lowercase, python-re

My code looks like :

```
import re

lst=[]

b = [('to', 1), ('Me', 2), ('And', 3), ('one', 5), ('listen', 6), ('up', 7)]

#print(type(b[2][0]))
count = 0 
for i in range(len(b)):
    
    if b[i][0].isupper():
        count = count + 1

        r = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', b[i][0])
        print(r)

print(count)
```

i want to see capitalized words as result , like :

```
["Me"]
["And"]
```

But i get nothing and the count shows 0 number of capitalized words!

The weird thing is if i use **islower()** it works and it shows all words that are not capitalized!!

```
import re

lst=[]

b = [('to', 1), ('Me', 2), ('And', 3), ('one', 5), ('listen', 6), ('up', 7)]

#print(type(b[2][0]))
count = 0 
for i in range(len(b)):
    
    if b[i][0].islower():
        count = count + 1

        r = re.findall('([a-z]+)', b[i][0])
        print(r)

print(count)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: `isupper` means "is all upper case". It doesn't mean "is some upper case".

Comment: okay . but why islower works?@Peaceful James

Comment: isupper() isn't meant for conversion to uppercase it just returns True/False depending upon the string passed. toupper() is the function for the conversion to uppercase.

Comment: @raven404 why islower() works?

Comment: isupper() checks whether all letters are in CAPS or not, whereas  islower() checks whether all letters are in small  case. And in your case ,there are no word with all CAPS but you do have words with all letters in small case like 'to', 'one', 'up' for which it works and  if condition becomes satisfied and it runs.

Comment: @raven404  thanks . that is great to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `istitle` instead of `isupper`.

```
import re

lst=[]

b = [('to', 1), ('Me', 2), ('And', 3), ('one', 5), ('listen', 6), ('up', 7)]

#print(type(b[2][0]))
count = 0 
for i in range(len(b)):
    
    if b[i][0].istitle():
        count = count + 1

        r = re.findall('([a-z]+)', b[i][0])
        print(r)

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

`islower` works because **every** character in `'one'` is small caps

`isupper` does not work because not **every** character in `'And'` is upper caps

to only check if the **first** character is upper caps use `istitle`

Furthermore, there are multiple enhancements to implement:

- for loop on word array
- dont use regex and use `istitle` that achieves the same purpose

```py
lst=[]
b = [('to', 1), ('Me', 2), ('And', 3), ('one', 5), ('listen', 6), ('up', 7)]

for word, _ in b:
    if word.istitle():
        lst.append(word)

print(lst)
```

Comment: you can also use a list comprehension, ```len([k for k, v in b if k.istitle()])```

Comment: tuple object has no attribute istitle()

Comment: @determindedElixir, tuple unpacking is required see the comment above.

Comment: my mistake, fixed